# PHP Error Reporting Production vs Development

Tags: php, error-reporting

What is best practice when setting error reporting on development and production applications? At the moment I have the following:

```
// development
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// production
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

Comment: My opinion - dev it to have 0 errors and set error_reporting to off on production unless you need it for debug

Comment: Disable `display_errors` in production

Comment: I've updated my question to confirm that display errors was off and log errors was on for live.

Comment: it's better turning `display_errors` off completely in *any* environment. Sometimes an error will cause headers to be sent too early, borking your script completely! Tail the log!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Quoting the [php-production.ini](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-production#L69) that should have come bundled with your PHP:

> ```
> ; PHP comes packaged with two INI files. One that is recommended to be used
> ; in production environments and one that is recommended to be used in
> ; development environments.
>
> ; php.ini-production contains settings which hold security, performance and
> ; best practices at its core. But please be aware, these settings may break
> ; compatibility with older or less security conscience applications. We
> ; recommending using the production ini in production and testing environments.
> ```

and further

> ```
> ; display_errors
> ;   Default Value: On
> ;   Development Value: On
> ;   Production Value: Off
>
> ; display_startup_errors
> ;   Default Value: Off
> ;   Development Value: On
> ;   Production Value: Off
>
> ; error_reporting
> ;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
> ;   Development Value: E_ALL
> ;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
>
> ; html_errors
> ;   Default Value: On
> ;   Development Value: On
> ;   Production value: On
>
> ; log_errors
> ;   Default Value: Off
> ;   Development Value: On
> ;   Production Value: On
> ```

Since you asked for best practise, I suggest you go with that.

Answer (score 3):

For the best error logging experience, set `error_reporting` to `-1` (absolutely everything), turn `display_errors` *off*, and set a custom `error_log`.

Then in the terminal, type `tail -f /path/to/error_log`. Your notices, warnings and errors will now scroll past in real time, without distorting your web page's display.

It's always worth logging everything. In any environment.

Comment: I had to work on a site that had so many notice errors that it was tricky to spot the /real/ errors. Also for some reason, one request was throwing a 500 error when logging all errors.

Comment: most notices just need simple fixes like `isset()` checks. And fixing a notice in a loop can drastically reduce the error log. Everything is an error! Get rid of them all! An empty log is a site that does what it's supposed to!