# php/mysql dynamic form fields are not inserted in my table

Tags: php, mysql, forms, dynamic, insert

I have a form that has a variable number of input fields, and i now try to get these values in my database. I got this code from another question here and all the replies where implying that they got it working..so i think i'm doing something wrong here.

I get no error, it just enters one empty entry/row in my database every time i submit the form. The $_POST array is filled with all the data i need, it shows when i print_r it.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


  if (
     !empty($_POST['homeTeam']) && !empty($_POST['awayTeam']) && !empty($_POST['homeWin']) && !empty($_POST['awayWin']) && 
     is_array($_POST['homeTeam']) && is_array($_POST['awayTeam']) && is_array($_POST['homeWin']) && is_array($_POST['awayWin']) && 
     count($_POST['homeWin']) === count($_POST['awayWin'])
  ) {
      $homeTeam_array = $_POST['homeTeam'];
      $awayTeam_array = $_POST['awayTeam'];
      $homeWin_array = $_POST['homeWin'];
      $awayWin_array = $_POST['awayWin'];

      for ($i = 0; $i < count($homeTeam_array); $i++) {

          $homeTeam = mysql_real_escape_string($homeTeam_array[$i]);
          $awayTeam = mysql_real_escape_string($awayTeam_array[$i]);
          $homeWin = mysql_real_escape_string($homeWin_array[$i]);
          $awayWin = mysql_real_escape_string($awayWin_array[$i]);

          $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO CalcOdds (homeTeam, awayTeam, homeWin, awayWin) VALUES ('$homeTeam', '$awayTeam', '$homeWin', '$awayWin')"; 
          $conn->query($sql);
          $conn->close();

      }
  }
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($_POST);
  echo "</pre>";
  echo 'Done!';
}

?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: You may want to share the content of `$_POST`

Comment: Why are you mixing `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions and where are you actually connecting to your database?

Comment: Thanks @tadman for the warning, i'll look into this.I only just picked up coding again after i while and really need to do some studying :)

Comment: You should also turn on error reporting during development, here is a SO question regarding this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602776/php-error-reporting-production-vs-development

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is because you have $conn->close(); inside the for loop try to add it after the loop like this:

```
     for ($i = 0; $i < count($homeTeam_array); $i++) {

          $homeTeam = mysql_real_escape_string($homeTeam_array[$i]);
          $awayTeam = mysql_real_escape_string($awayTeam_array[$i]);
          $homeWin = mysql_real_escape_string($homeWin_array[$i]);
          $awayWin = mysql_real_escape_string($awayWin_array[$i]);

          $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO CalcOdds (homeTeam, awayTeam, homeWin, awayWin) VALUES ('$homeTeam', '$awayTeam', '$homeWin', '$awayWin')"; 
          $conn->query($sql);            
      }
      $conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of doing !empty() I'd do isset()
2. By the looks of things you haven't actually established a connection to your database.
3. Make sure that the data actually gets through the if() statement by using a echo() for example.