# ErrorException Undefined variable After moving to laravel helper functions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7.2

I've got an old website which once was in vanilla php. I migrated to laravel putting the whole code under a 'legacy-folder' in views and I had a folder with a lot of functions in it.

Everything was running fine at this point.

In order to go one step further I moved the functions from the folder inside views into helpers. Now I get a few type of errors repeated everywhere in the codebase, I'm debugging them but they are a lot and I don't know why they are thrown now and not before.

For example errors are now thrown if:

- undefined index of an array is accessed

  $a = $_GET['a'];
- undefined property of object is accessed

  $a = $b->c;
- I try to enqueue an unset variable to itself

  $a .= " example";
- foreach on unset variable is called
- function is passed an unset variabile

This is my routes/web.php

```
Route::get('{path?}', 'LegacyPagesController@show')->where('path', '.+');
Route::post('{path?}', 'LegacyPagesController@show')->where('path', '.+');
```

LegacyPagesController

```
public function show($path='index.php')
{
  ob_start();
  require(base_path('resources/views/legacy-pages/').$path);
  return ob_get_clean();
}
```

I've put the helpers in App\Helpers\ExampleHelper.php as classless collection of functions and in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/ExampleHelper.php",
```

I'm not sure if these errors are related to the new helpers or a mistake in my routing or if anything else might be involved like php version or php.ini configuration. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What version of PHP and Laravel are you using? I'm guessing when you moved to laravel it required a higher version of PHP that now throw errors instead of warnings for those things.

Comment: I moved to laravel and upgraded to php 7 in different moments and everything was working. Right now I only moved the helpers function but a lot of time have passed and there might be some changes on the web server I'm not aware of. Anyway laravel 5.2 and php 7.2

Comment: It sounds like your php error reporting settings was changes to show notices. Else it could be your env has debug enabled.

Comment: They are not just showing, they are blocking execution. Can notices do this? Debug is indeed enabled because it's my testing environment as it was before these changes

Comment: Should only block if strict is enabled.

Comment: @OliverNybroe that's it. ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_STRICT); solve it for me. Can you make it an answer so I can accept it? Thanks. btw is it advisable to use E_STRICT or is it fine to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the error message you see, just change your `error_reporting` variable like so:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);
```

It is recommended to have it on and instead fix the errors, as it is indeed errors, php is just smart enough to handle them for you.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50603127/2304480) shows the recommended settings from the php team.