# How to upload 2 file from 2 single input file to database with PHP and VUEJS

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

is there anyway using move_uploaded_file which upload 2 file from 2 file input?

**file.vue (template)**

```
<input type="file" id="ob_ssm_document" ref="ob_ssm_document" required/>                    
<input type="file" id="ob_business_license" ref="ob_business_license" required />
<v-btn color="green darken-1" text @click="processSubmit()">Confirm</v-btn>
```

//file.vue (script)

```
processSubmit(){
  this.ob_ssm_document = this.$refs.ob_ssm_document.files[0];
  this.ob_business_license = this.$refs.ob_business_license.files[0];

  this.axios.post('businessfile.php', formImage,{
       headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
       }
  }).then((response) => {
       if(!response.data){
           this.fileError = true;
       } else {
          alert("submitted");
       }
  }
```

**businessfile.php**

```
<?php

// File name
$ob_ssm_document = $_FILES['ob_ssm_document']['name'];
$ob_business_license = $_FILES['ob_business_license']['name'];

// Valid file extensions
$valid_extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","png","pdf");

// File extension
$extension = pathinfo($ob_ssm_document, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$extension_two = pathinfo($ob_business_license, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check extension
if(in_array(strtolower($extension,$extension_two),$valid_extensions) ) {

   // Upload file
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ob_ssm_document']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$ob_ssm_document) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ob_business_license']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$ob_business_license)){
      echo 1;
   }else{
      echo 0;
   }

}else{
   echo 0;
}

exit;
```

personalfile.php

```
<?php

// File name
$ob_ssm_document = $_FILES['ob_ssm_document']['name'];

// Valid file extensions
$valid_extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","png","pdf");

// File extension
$extension = pathinfo($ob_ssm_document, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check extension
if(in_array(strtolower($extension,$extension_two),$valid_extensions) ) {

   // Upload file
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ob_ssm_document']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$ob_ssm_document)){
      echo 1;
   }else{
      echo 0;
   }

}else{
   echo 0;
}
```

exit;
The code above is for 1 file from 1 single input file to database

What i really want is upload two file from 2 diffrernt file input into the folder name called "Uploads" with each file's name.

Comment: You forgot to explain what the problem with is.

Comment: For your test, you should turn on error reporting, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602776/php-error-reporting-production-vs-development

Comment: HINT: In the errorlog there should be a line like `Warning: strtolower() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given`

Comment: Hey Luuk, thank you for the comment, the issue is it failled to submit the 2 file into the database. There is no error in console but the database does not appear any file. I've tried to submit 1 file, it works with the code above but there is some modify with some code above. Let me add 1 more personalfile.php which is the file that is work with 1 file.

Comment: re-read the HINT i gave and, if not clear, respond to it. (Please)

Comment: I've added 1 file with the name php-production.ini and deploy along with the file.php. When i run the function, it will show the error log is that right?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by your last comment, but to add to the HINT, please have a look at [strtolower()](https://www.php.net/strtolower), and tell me what the output of this function will be when you use two parameters.

Comment: Im so sorry that giving the confusing statement. To make it clear for you, [link](https://www.webslesson.info/2020/04/vue-js-file-upload-with-php-axios.html) This is the website that i refer to learn how to submit 1 image to database. But this time my function will be submitting 2 image to database.

Comment: Did this last link help?